# Vertical align my loader within app-root - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have implemented a simple spinner within my `<app-root>` of `index.html` such that it appears something is happening behind the scenes, rather than a blank white page until my app loads fully.

However, I cannot seem to get it vertically aligned in the centre of the page. I don't want to affect how the contents of my app are loaded as they themselves are vertically centred.

Is there something I'm missing?

I thought of nesting my spinner in another `div` and setting that to have a specific height, then centring within that, but it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

I have also thought about using:

```
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

**[Codepen for this 'solution'](https://codepen.io/physicsboy/pen/wEWJYJ)**

However, with how things are, it appears that it sets the positioning based on the top left corner of the overall `div` area, therefore appears offset to the left and the bottom by however large the spinner is.

**[Codepen for just centred horizontally](https://codepen.io/physicsboy/pen/RYRpMN)**

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    .loader {
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid red;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
      margin: auto;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>BettingUi</title>
  <base href="./">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700|Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <!--<app-root>-->
    <!--
      This will display a loader while the app is loading - in case of slow connection
      We cannot use an Angular component here as it will only be displayed after loading
      all component - so direct HTML here is the best case for this.
    -->
    <div class="loader"></div>
  <!--</app-root>-->
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**
I did manage to find a solution myself to this:

```
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: calc(50% - 60px);
left: calc(50% - 60px);
```

Here I decided that, because the spinner was being centred based on the top left corner of the 'square' that defines the width/height of the element, it would make sense to simply edge back by half of the actual width & height.

[**Final codepen**](https://codepen.io/physicsboy/pen/oPLwbe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.parent{
  height:90vh;
  display:flex;
  postion:absolute;
}

.loader {
      border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border-top: 16px solid red;
      width: 120px;
      height: 120px;
      animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
      margin: auto  ;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
      0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
      100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

.container {
  
  background: grey;
  margin: auto;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="loader"></div>
</div>
```

This will achieve the desired effect, when doing a spinner my go to strategy is to first create a transparent container (in the example .parent) which will have the size of the visible area and position absolute (so that it overlays everything) and after that placing the spinner inside the container.

P.S. Believe me it's elegant enough, also a must to have (the container `<div>`), because no matter what you are doing you must have some kind of container, by which dimensions you spinner will be aligned. If you are using Angular2 you can place the spinner with the overlay and all related html and styles in separate component, so that in your root `index.html` it will look  just like `<spinner></spinner>`

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to get it working as just <spinner></spinner>?
If you are referring to creating a component for the spinner and loading this, then that is not an option as this will take time to load. I have tested this already. But if you are referring to a different method, I'd be interested to see what you mean.

Comment: My bad, i had missed the line (shame on me) that you are using this spinner while "preloading"  the app, either way the strategy with the `.container` and  `.spinner` <div> is still the right  way to go, for the reasons i mentioned above.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks for the help and explanation :-)